# Nodes/Attributes that starts with a number?

Tags: xml, syntax

Actually i use my firm-name as xml-node. Actually we change the firm's name with a leading number (like 7zip, but not 7zip, just for example).

Is this valid xml?

```
<1000questions 1000question="often" />
```

Comment: Have you bothered to check the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In XML, both element and attribute names are [not allowed](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#sec-common-syn) to begin with an ASCII digit. What you show is therefore not valid XML.

Answer (score 5):

This info can be found in the w3c website. Here's the relevant excerpt:

> XML Naming Rules
>
> XML elements must follow these naming rules:
>
> Names can contain letters, numbers, and other characters
>
> **Names cannot start with a number or punctuation character**
>
> Names cannot start with the letters xml (or XML, or Xml, etc)
>
> Names cannot contain spaces

source: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_elements.asp

One suggestion, from the top of my head, is to fake `1000` with alpha characters, `IOOO` for instance.